# If $a^3=1$, is $G$ abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

If $G$ is a group that satisfies $a^3=1$ for every $a\in G$, then is $G$ abelian?

This is an exercise I found in Jacobson's Basic Algebra. It is analogous to the question: If $G$ is a group that satisfies $a^2=1$ for every $a\in G$, then $G$ is abelian. I tried to multiply on both sides of $ab$ ($a,b\in G$) by some appropriate ($b***$) and ($***a$) three times to yield $ba$ but failed. Nor could I give a counterexample. Can someone give me an answer to the question and some hints to solve it?

Comment: No, but it is nilpotent of class at most $3$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The multiplicative group of matrices
$$G = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} \middle\vert\,  a,b,c \in \mathbb{F}_3\right\} \subset \operatorname{Mat}(3 \times 3, \mathbb{F}_3)$$
is a counterexample (it is isomorphic to the group in Joanpemo's answer).

---

For all those who are not willing to check this example on there own, here are the arguments:

- Every element $g \in G$ has characteristic polynomial $\chi_g(\lambda) = \lambda^3 - 1$, and thus has order $3$ by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.
- The elements $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ do not commute:
  $$ \begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} $$
  $$ \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Very good. You should change your username to "Heisenbergs Wohnzimmer".

Answer (score 5):

Nope. The (non-trivial) semidirect product $\;C_3\ltimes(C_3\times C_3)\;$ has exponent $\;3\;$ and it is certainly non-abelian.

Comment: I'm a beginner in the group theory.Could you please explain what you mean by C3?

Comment: $\;C_n:=$ the cyclic group of order $\;n\;$. This notation is usually used for the *multiplicative* case, whereas the additive case is many times denoted by $\;\Bbb Z_n=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$